# I have a single line list and want to covert it to a multi dimensional list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file that I converted into a list, but I want it to be a multi-dimensional list. Is there a way to do this easily?

This is my code:

```
crimefile = open(fileName, 'r')
yourResult = [line.split(',') for line in crimefile.readlines()]
```

Comment: So; what's the problem with your current implementation?

Comment: It only prints out on 1 line. I have a huge list of a couple thousand numbers and i want to only have 6 or 7 numbers on each line.

Comment: It's fine if it prints out on one line; so long as you see a nested lists inside your list? I have duplicated your lines and made my own file according to what your code is looking for and see no issue with the output.

Comment: No the thing is i want to only get certain columns for the project that I'm doing.I want to get the numbers in mass amounts from the columns.

Comment: What i wanted to use is this: print([col[1]for col in yourResult]) to get one of the columns but i can't do that with a one line list

Answer (score 0):

Your code does create a 2-dimensional list (assuming your file is multiple lines of numbers where each number is separated by a comma). If you want to print out each individual list in `yourResult`, try this: `for list in yourResult: print (list)` To access a certain item in the list, for example the first number on each line, simply replace `print (list)` with `print (list[0])`

Comment: How would i put commas in between so i could get the first number on each line is there a way?

Comment: Something like this (in your text file):
`123,2537864, 2395, 4283905,2345,2345,  2435`
In your text file, each line is a list, but I can't insert lines in a comment. Multiple lines are okay. Spaces shouldn't affect your program, just make sure there are commas between all your numbers (one isn't needed at the end of the line).
Hope this helps!